# How to disappear keyboard from UITextView when touch in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I don't want to appear any keyboard when i touched UITextView in iOS.
How can i do that?

Comment: @AshleyMills I could imagine you would want a UITextField editable during 'edit' mode and non-editable otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the UITextView non-editable.

```
UITextView* tv = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[tv setEditable:NO];
```

Comment: How will the user edit the text field without a keyboard? By setting a UIControl that deals with text to non-editable it implicitly prevents the keyboard from popping up.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclassing UITextView and override "-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder", returning NO.